# Vagrant laravel/homestead shared folders not mounting after 2.1.0 update

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have scoured the internet up and down for this issue and always consider asking here a last resort. That being said if this has been asked and solved before please point me in the right direction.

I am using Virtualbox 5.1.22 on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 with vagrant version 1.9.6

Yesterday I upgraded my homestead box from version 2.0.0 to 2.1.0. I only upgraded after running vagrant up and it did its thing and was fine until I come in today and turn my machine one and try booting up the vagrant machine again. I get the following error at the end of the normal stuff:

```
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=900,gid=900 vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the command was:

/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

I have tried vagrant reload, vagrant halt and then vagrant up, restarting the machine and re-running, vagrant reload --provision

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: Why the downvote? This seems like a perfectly reasonable question?

Comment: do you have guest additions ? it might need to be updated, best is to use the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest)

Comment: Yeah turns out I have to add the plugin...really annoying as it just worked before so I don't see why i now need a plugin...

Comment: if you dont want the plugin, you can update yourself, I find the plugin quite convenient

Comment: Update what if I don't want the plugin? Everything is latest version...

Comment: update your guest addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box comes with [VirtualBox Guest Addition](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) for a given version of VirtualBox, which is not the one you're running on your host.

what you need to do is update the Guest Additions in your guest VM to the same version of VirtualBox that you run on your host machine.

1. The easy way as mentioned in my comments is to use the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest), it will compare the version from your host and guest software and will automatically aligned if needed. I find it pretty convenient and there are options to disable the update if you need.
2. In case you do not want to run an additional plugin, you can make the update on the guest VM manually.

You will need to download the Guest Addition for the same version of your VirtualBox ([5.1.22](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.22/) in your case) and follow the [instructions to install](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#mountingadditionsiso)

Answer (score 0):

So I found and installed this: https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest

I have no idea why I need a plugin now when it was working just fine before updating but hey...it works.